# Django: Allow admin user to edit site-wide settings?

Tags: django, django-settings

I have a Django site, and I'd like to allow a couple of site-wide settings:

```
ADMIN_EMAIL - email address for an administrative user
REMINDER_TEXT - email text for an email that the site will generate once a week
```

to be edited in the admin interface.

What is the most sensible way to do this? Should I store these values in `settings.py`, or somewhere in the database?

[This previous SO question seems to be related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018031/make-settings-py-customizable-from-user-input), but I don't think it's ever been fully answered.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, `settings.py` has to be accessed very rarely, because each access consists in exposing important data (db password for instance). So the best place to store extra settings is definitely a database table - a two column table, with the settings key and the actual settings data will suffice.

Comment: Thank you. Any idea how I could disable the 'add new' button in the Django admin - i.e. how I could make this a model field that only ever contains one entry?

Comment: Late to the party, and I really hope you solved this before now. For posterity, you can remove access to "create" by disabling the permission `<app> | <model> | Can add <model>` for the relevant group or user.

Answer (score 4):

I've tried dbsettings (as well as the newer fork of it on github), and they are useful - but a bit too heavy-weight for my needs.  Instead, I implemented a simpler method.  I did it using a JSONField (from Postgres 9.3) - but you might prefer to use a TextField (use max_length=1000 or somesuch) as it's simpler to explain to people how to enter a string instead of JSON:

1) First, build your own Settings Model (maybe in core/models.py):

```
class Setting(models.Model):
    """
    Model for site-wide settings.
    """
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, help_text="Name of site-wide variable")
    value = JSONField(null=True, blank=True, help_text="Value of site-wide variable that scripts can reference - must be valid JSON")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

2) Then, add an admin interface (in core/admin.py):

```
class SettingAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['name', 'value']

admin.site.register(Setting, SettingAdmin)
```

3) Build and run your migrations:

```
python manage.py schemamigration core --auto
python manage.py migrate core
```

4) Add to the top of base.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Auto-exported site-wide settings
    {% autoescape off %}var site_settings = {{ settings|safe|default:"{}" }};{% endautoescape %}
</script>
```

5) Build an 'injector' that adds code to every request (likely in core/contextprocessors.py)

```
from models import Setting
import json

def app_settings(request):
    """Global values to pass to templates"""
    settings_dict = dict()
    settings = dict()
    for obj in Setting.objects.all():
        settings[obj.name] = obj.value
    settings_dict['settings'] = json.dumps(settings)
    return settings_dict
```

5) Then, add the context processors to your site settings.py:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    ...,
    '<yourapp>.core.contextprocessors.app_settings',
)
```

6) Log into your admin page via browser and create a setting:

```
http://yoursite/admin/core/setting/
Add a new setting, something like:
    cell_status_colors
with a value of: 
    ["green","red"] (note this has to be valid JSON, so use quotes around strings)

or:
    daily_header
with a value of:
    {"text":"Tomorrow only, free shipping!"}
```

7) And finally, each of your javascript files should be able to call these via standard JS:

```
var colors = site_settings.cell_status_colors || ["green","red"];
var msg_text = site_settings.daily_header || {"text":""};
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some applications, that allows django admins to define and use some settings through site-wide... One of those such applications(which i used) is dbsettings...

[dbsettings applicaton...](http://code.google.com/p/django-values/)