# Django: query database at fixed interval and send email?

Tags: django

I have a Django site and once a week, I'd like to query the database and send an email based on that query.

It's a library site, and I want to query the list of users, find each user's checked-out books, and email each user.

The process is something like this (pseudocode):

```
for user in users:
    get user.email_address
    get user.books
    get intro_text and from_address (global for the site)
    create email for user
    send email
```

There's also the complication that `intro_text` and `from_address` need to be configurable through the admin interface. I'm planning to [store these in the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4876462/django-allow-admin-user-to-edit-site-wide-settings), rather than in `settings.py`.

I'm guessing I should create this as a Django management task that I can then run as a cron job - would that be a sensible approach?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: hi, can you please explain how can i do it in little more detail. I am also implementing something like this, where i have to query database to get the user emails and messages and send them email   at a particular time each day. I would really appreciate if you could provide details regarding setting up django task and setting up cron job. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, management task + cron job is the way to go here.

Comment: @daniel hi can you give more details as to how can i implement this i.e query database to get user emails and then at a particular time each day send out email.