# What are the ways to make it possible to change banner image of site directly through django admin?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

I know how to make it possible to create/edit/delete a multiple-row database model through django admin page. But let's say I want to make it possible to modify the single banner image of my site through admin page, what am I supposed to do then?

Should I create an entire database model for one item? Or is there a better way to implement this?

Comment: database can be the simplest and the fastest method to resolve this problem - and you could do it in 5 minutes. Any other method may need much more time and much more code. Today you may need this only for banner but tomorrow you can use this database for other settings - if you create two columns `key` and `value`

Comment: [Django: Allow admin user to edit site-wide settings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4876462/django-allow-admin-user-to-edit-site-wide-settings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either create your own model for these types of settings, or you can use one of the many packages designed to handle this type of situation:

https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/live-setting/